# Installing pip on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu, pip

I was installing `pip` for python3. I used the following command for that:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pip
```

[image]

But after installation it still says `pip` is not installed.

[image]

I have `python 3.5.2` installed.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `python3-pip` package installs pip for Python 3, which is named `pip3`.  Plain `pip` is pip for Python 2, which is installed by the `python-pip` package.

Comment: oh that was it! I need one clarification here, does all python3 related packages contain `3` as suffix?

Comment: @Shaharyar: Yes.

Answer (score 7):

The best way to install it, is by :

`wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py`

`cd ~/Downloads/` (if your version is english, in french you find it `Téléchargements`)

Then once you downloaded it, try :

`sudo python3 get-pip.py`

Comment: I did the same, but showed following error `python3: can't open file 'get-pip.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory`. The other answer solved my issue. Thanks

Comment: check where the file got downloaded, it seems it downloaded it to `~/Downloads/`

Answer (score -4):

easy_install -U pip : this solved my problem on ubuntu 16.04