# Unable to install python pip on UBuntu 16.04

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, pip

This is the command I used to install python pip

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pip
```

I got this error

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 linux-generic-hwe-16.04 : Depends: linux-headers-generic-hwe-16.04 (= 4.10.0.28.31) but 4.8.0.36.8 is to be installed
 python3-pip : Depends: python-pip-whl (= 8.1.1-2ubuntu0.6) but it is not going to be installed
               Recommends: python3-dev (>= 3.2) but it is not going to be installed
               Recommends: python3-setuptools but it is not going to be installed
               Recommends: python3-wheel but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

I have tried to run "apt-get -f install" as given but it is again giving the same error

python 3.5.2 is used

Please explain me how to solve this issue

update:-
`sudo apt-get install -f` 
This command has solved the above problem.

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49817590/installing-pip-on-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04, `sudo apt update && sudo apt install python3-pip` : ... additional packages will be installed: python-pip-whl python3-setuptools python3-wheel → No issues.

Comment: @KnudLarsen I tried it, apt was update but after that I got same error. In the above error  this line "linux-generic-hwe-16.04 : Depends: linux-headers-generic-hwe-16.04 (= 4.10.0.28.31) but 4.8.0.36.8 is to be installed" so according to it do I need to change something like version . I am not clear with this statement.

Comment: `Ubuntu 16.04 LTS EOL Apr 2021` ... sounds like a perfect time to update your OS?